# Override metabase function in docker image

Tags: clojure, metabase

So metabase does `select true from table limit 0` against every table/view in the database to see if they are readable.  Problem is when a redshift view has references enough spectrum tables that can take multiple minutes per view, causing high cpu usage and eventually a timeout in the sync process.  I want to override [this function](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/7c47e04bc7c8d32a3a30f9be4d622631459c9ca4/src/metabase/driver/sql_jdbc/sync/describe_database.clj#L82) so it just returns true for everything, doesn't try to query the database.  However, I want to keep using the default metabase dockerhub distributable so I don't need to fork or do anything else crazy.  Can I somehow embed a clojure [with-redefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899108/clojure-overriding-one-function-in-a-library) into a [external plugin](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/installation-and-operation/running-metabase-on-docker#adding-external-dependencies-or-plugins) so that metabase will load the plugin and it'll override that function?